# How to save previous filter settings for report using SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, cookies, reporting-services, reporting

I have a report running on SQL Server Reporting Services which is rendered in browser. It has several report parameters. Is there  any way to save values of the parameters for next run? For example, I set parameter "Results from date" to some day in the past, view report, then close browser and then open it again - the value of this parameter will be date which was set in my previous session. Is it possible?

Comment: You can set the default values for the parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2008/01/report-parameter-selection-memory/) little gem.

From the article:

> ...a method of enhancing Reporting Services reports to make
>   them ... remember the parameter selections so that next time they run
>   the report they haven’t got to re-select the same parameters.